# Laravel Form::open to the same url

Tags: laravel-4

I have a route: resetPassword which accepts two parameters: code and userid. The code and userid are accepted through a get String. On this route, I render a form to accept the new password (entered twice).
so the url looks something like:`/resetPasssword?code=asfsanj38uan&user=14`
I want the form on this page to post back to `/resetPasssword?code=asfsanj38uan&user=14` instead of to `/resetPassword`.

I've tried `Form::open("url"=>Request::url())` and leaving the url blank but in both cases, it strips the extra parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Request::fullUrl()` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to leave it blank, so the browser will post the form to the same page url.
I'm not sure the url parameters will be taken, so you should changes your routes.

instead of :

> get /resetPassword with code and users as parameters

put them in the url :

> get /resetPassword/{user_id}/{code}

so these two values will be parameters of the function in your controller.
Then you can open your form with

> Form::open()

and the browser will submit to that same url for sure.